# Как обнулить цикл. При выполнении elif, итератор j должен заново пробегаться, уже с элемента counter -1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
spisok = list()
for i in range(n):
    name = input()
    spisok.append(name)
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
counter = 0
spisok1 = list()
for j in spisok:
    counter += 1
    if counter % a != 0:
        spisok1.append(str(j))
    elif counter % a == 0:
        del spisok[:counter - 1]
        counter = 0

for k in spisok1:
    print(k)
```

Формат ввода
На первой строке вводится натуральное число N — количество солдат.
Далее следуют имена солдат в количестве N штук на отдельных строках.
Далее на отдельной строке следует натуральное число K — наряд получит каждый K-й солдат.
Наконец, на последней строке указывается натуральное число M — сколько раз будет повторено наказание каждого K-го.

Формат вывода
Нужно вывести на отдельных строках в том же порядке имена всех тех солдат, которых минует наказание.

Comment: Никак. Во-первых, по списку можно сразу идти с нужным шагом. А во-вторых, по списку можно пройтись и два раза. Или даже три!

Comment: Тогда объясните пожалуйста, как отредактировать код

Comment: Просто в elif (который вообще-то в данном случае можно написать как else) ничего не делать (т.е. вообще его выкинуть).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде же не сложно пройтись по списку и добавлять в новый все элементы кроме К-тых. Повторить М раз.

```
N = int(input())
names = [input() for _ in range(N)]
K = int(input())
M = int(input())
for _ in range(M):
    names = [name for i, name in enumerate(names, 1) if i % K != 0]
print(names)
```

Или тоже самое без list comprehensions.

```
N = int(input())
names = []
for _ in range(N):
    names.append(input())
K = int(input())
M = int(input())
for _ in range(M):
    new_names = []
    i = 1
    for name in names:
        if i % K != 0:
            new_names.append(name)
        i += 1
    names = new_names
print(names)
```